# Pivot Table Datafields combined under Column Field from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am creating a database in sheet one from various tables, this datasource is now my source for my pivot table on tab 2 all generated from vb.net.
I have 2 datafields I would like to add.

```
Dim pivotField As Excel.PivotField
'Row field 1
pivotField = pivotTbl.PivotFields("Grade")
    With pivotField
        .Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField
        .Name = " Grade"
    End With
'Row field 2
pivotField = pivotTbl.PivotFields("Financed")
    With pivotField
        .Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField
        .Name = " Financed"
    End With
'DATA FIELD 1 and 2
pivotField = pivotTbl.PivotFields("OnHand")
    With pivotField
        .Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
        .Function = Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "### ### ### ##0.000"
        .Name = " Stock On Hand"
        .Position = 1
    End With

    pivotField = pivotTbl.PivotFields("StockValue")
    With pivotField
        .Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField
        .Function = Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum
        .NumberFormat = "### ### ### ##0.000"
        .Name = " Stock Value"
        .Position = 2
    End With
```

The data fields are being created, however, they are both listed under one COLUMN when I view the sheet after it has been created.

If I click on the pivot table, and move those fields out of the VALUES and then back in the values, it splits out the pivot correctly, and adds a row header above called DATA and has the 2 datafields under their own columns, as I wish it to be.

PIVOT as created from code above

[image: Pivot Before]

structure of PIVOT above as created from code

[image: Pivot Before Structure]

After manually moving the "Sum Of" Values from Rows to Columns, it looks like this:

AFTER Changes

[image: After Image]

And this is the structure edited:

[image: After Structure]

I would like to know how to move the VALUES from rows to columns in the code? especially as I never specified it to be in the ROWS in the first place, seems to be some default setting I need to change, I have looked all over and cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just access the “DATA” portion of the pivot as follows and make set it to be a datafield

```
   pivotField = pivotTbl.PivotFields("Data")
   pivotField.Orientation = Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField
```

You're Wellcome